# webgl черный экран

Tags: javascript, webgl

Что я делаю не так? [рабочий пример](https://jsfiddle.net/mihinov/dLc34sxm/)

```js
function drawWebglCanvas(f, v, gl, image) {
  function resizeGlAndCanvas(gl) {
    resizeCanvas(gl);
    const resizeFunc = () => {
      resizeCanvas(gl);
      render();
    };
    const lazyFunc = debounce(resizeFunc, 100);
    window.addEventListener('resize', lazyFunc);
  }
  resizeGlAndCanvas(gl);

  const vertexShader = createShader(gl, gl.VERTEX_SHADER, v);
  const fragmentShader = createShader(gl, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER, f);
  const program = createProgram(gl, vertexShader, fragmentShader);


  const positionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'a_position');
  const texcoordLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "a_texCoord");

  const positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
  setRectangle(gl, 0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

  const texCoordBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, texCoordBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([
    0.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 1.0,
    0.0, 1.0,
    1.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 1.0
  ]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

  // создаём текстуру
  const texture = gl.createTexture();
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);

  // задаём параметры, чтобы можно было отрисовать изображение любого размера
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);

  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);

  // lookup uniforms
  const resolutionLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_resolution");
  const textureSizeLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_textureSize");
  const kernelLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_kernel[0]");
  const kernelWeightLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_kernelWeight");


  const kernels = {
    normal: [
      0, 0, 0,
      0, 1, 0,
      0, 0, 0
    ],
    gaussianBlur: [
      0.045, 0.122, 0.045,
      0.122, 0.332, 0.122,
      0.045, 0.122, 0.045
    ],
    gaussianBlur2: [
      1, 2, 1,
      2, 4, 2,
      1, 2, 1
    ],
    gaussianBlur3: [
      0, 1, 0,
      1, 1, 1,
      0, 1, 0
    ],
    unsharpen: [-1, -1, -1, -1, 9, -1, -1, -1, -1],
    sharpness: [
      0, -1, 0, -1, 5, -1,
      0, -1, 0
    ],
    sharpen: [-1, -1, -1, -1, 16, -1, -1, -1, -1],
    edgeDetect: [-0.125, -0.125, -0.125, -0.125, 1, -0.125, -0.125, -0.125, -0.125],
    edgeDetect2: [-1, -1, -1, -1, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1],
    edgeDetect3: [-5, 0, 0,
      0, 0, 0,
      0, 0, 5
    ],
    edgeDetect4: [-1, -1, -1,
      0, 0, 0,
      1, 1, 1
    ],
    edgeDetect5: [-1, -1, -1,
      2, 2, 2, -1, -1, -1
    ],
    edgeDetect6: [-5, -5, -5, -5, 39, -5, -5, -5, -5],
    sobelHorizontal: [
      1, 2, 1,
      0, 0, 0, -1, -2, -1
    ],
    sobelVertical: [
      1, 0, -1,
      2, 0, -2,
      1, 0, -1
    ],
    previtHorizontal: [
      1, 1, 1,
      0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1
    ],
    previtVertical: [
      1, 0, -1,
      1, 0, -1,
      1, 0, -1
    ],
    boxBlur: [
      0.111, 0.111, 0.111,
      0.111, 0.111, 0.111,
      0.111, 0.111, 0.111
    ],
    triangleBlur: [
      0.0625, 0.125, 0.0625,
      0.125, 0.25, 0.125,
      0.0625, 0.125, 0.0625
    ],
    emboss: [-2, -1, 0, -1, 1, 1,
      0, 1, 2
    ]
  };

  const initialSelection = 'edgeDetect2';

  const ui = document.querySelector("#ui");
  const select = document.createElement("select");

  for (let name in kernels) {
    const option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = name;
    if (name === initialSelection) {
      option.selected = true;
    }
    option.appendChild(document.createTextNode(name));
    select.appendChild(option);
  }

  select.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    drawWithKernel(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);
  });
  ui.appendChild(select);
  drawWithKernel(initialSelection);

  function computeKernelWeight(kernel) {
    const weight = kernel.reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr);
    return weight <= 0 ? 1 : weight;
  }

  function drawWithKernel(name) {
    gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.useProgram(program);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(texcoordLocation);
    //gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, texcoordBuffer);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(texcoordLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.uniform2f(resolutionLocation, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
    gl.uniform2f(textureSizeLocation, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
    gl.uniform1fv(kernelLocation, kernels[name]);
    gl.uniform1f(kernelWeightLocation, computeKernelWeight(kernels[name]));
    render();
  }

  function render() {
    const primitiveType = gl.TRIANGLES;
    const offset = 0;
    const count = 6;
    gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.drawArrays(primitiveType, offset, count);
  }
}

function setRectangle(gl, x, y, width, height) {
  const x1 = x;
  const x2 = x + width;
  const y1 = y;
  const y2 = y + height;
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([
    x1, y1,
    x2, y1,
    x1, y2,
    x1, y2,
    x2, y1,
    x2, y2,
  ]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
}

function sendGetRequest(url) {
  return fetch(url).then(response => response.text());
}

function debounce(f, t) {
  return function(args) {
    let previousCall = this.lastCall;
    this.lastCall = Date.now();
    if (previousCall && ((this.lastCall  -  previousCall) <= t)) {
      clearTimeout(this.lastCallTimer);
    }
    this.lastCallTimer = setTimeout(() => f(args), t);
  }
}

function createShader(gl, type, source) {
  const shader = gl.createShader(type);
  gl.shaderSource(shader, source);
  gl.compileShader(shader);
  const sucess = gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS);
  if (sucess) {
    return shader;
  }

  console.log(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
  gl.deleteShader(shader);
}

function createProgram(gl, v, f) {
  const program = gl.createProgram();
  gl.attachShader(program, v);
  gl.attachShader(program, f);
  gl.linkProgram(program);
  const sucess = gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.LINK_STATUS);
  if (sucess) {
    return program;
  }

  console.log(gl.getProgramInfoLog(program));
  gl.deleteProgram(program);
}

function resizeCanvas(gl) {
  const realToCSSPixels = window.devicePixelRatio; // для дисплеев повышенной четкости HD-DPI
  const width = Math.floor(gl.canvas.scrollWidth * realToCSSPixels);
  const height = Math.floor(gl.canvas.scrollHeight * realToCSSPixels);
  gl.canvas.width = width;
  gl.canvas.height = height;
  gl.viewport(0, 0, width, height);
}

function requestCORSIfNotSameOrigin(img, url) {
  if ((new URL(url)).origin !== window.location.origin) {
    img.crossOrigin = "";
  }
}

const fragment = document.querySelector('#fragment-shader-2d').innerText;
const vertex = document.querySelector('#vertex-shader-2d').innerText;
const canvas = document.querySelector('#glcanvas');
const gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
const image = new Image();
const url = "https://picsum.photos/1000/700";
requestCORSIfNotSameOrigin(image, url);
image.src = url;
image.addEventListener('load', () => {
  drawWebglCanvas(fragment, vertex, gl, image);
});
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body,
html {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

#glcanvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#uiContainer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 3%;
 top: 3%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="uiContainer">
    <div id="ui"></div>
</div>

<script  id="vertex-shader-2d" type="not-js">
attribute vec2 a_texCoord;

attribute vec2 a_position;
uniform vec2 u_resolution;

varying vec2 v_texCoord;

void main() {
    // преобразуем положение в пикселях к диапазону от 0.0 до 1.0
    vec2 zeroToOne = a_position / u_resolution;

    // преобразуем из 0->1 в 0->2
    vec2 zeroToTwo = zeroToOne * 2.0;

    // преобразуем из 0->2 в -1->+1 (пространство отсечения)
    vec2 clipSpace = zeroToTwo - 1.0;

    gl_Position = vec4(clipSpace * vec2(1, -1), 0, 1);

    v_texCoord = a_texCoord;
}
</script>

<script  id="fragment-shader-2d" type="not-js">
precision mediump float;

uniform sampler2D u_image; // наша текстура
uniform vec2 u_textureSize; // размер текстуры
uniform float u_kernel[9];
uniform float u_kernelWeight;

varying vec2 v_texCoord; // texCoords, переданные из вершинного шейдера

void main(){
    // рассчитываем один пиксель в текстурных координатах
    vec2 onePixel = vec2(1.0, 1.0) / u_textureSize;

    vec4 colorSum =
        texture2D(u_image, v_texCoord + onePixel * vec2(-1, -1)) * u_kernel[0] +
        texture2D(u_image, v_texCoord + onePixel * vec2( 0, -1)) * u_kernel[1] +
        texture2D(u_image, v_texCoord + onePixel * vec2( 1, -1)) * u_kernel[2] +
        texture2D(u_image, v_texCoord + onePixel * vec2(-1,  0)) * u_kernel[3] +
        texture2D(u_image, v_texCoord + onePixel * vec2( 0,  0)) * u_kernel[4] +
        texture2D(u_image, v_texCoord + onePixel * vec2( 1,  0)) * u_kernel[5] +
        texture2D(u_image, v_texCoord + onePixel * vec2(-1,  1)) * u_kernel[6] +
        texture2D(u_image, v_texCoord + onePixel * vec2( 0,  1)) * u_kernel[7] +
        texture2D(u_image, v_texCoord + onePixel * vec2( 1,  1)) * u_kernel[8] ;

    gl_FragColor = vec4((colorSum / u_kernelWeight).rgb, 1.0);
}
</script>
<canvas id="glcanvas">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Очень глупо, но я создал переменную `texCoordBuffer`, а пытался обратиться к `texcoordBuffer`, у меня в прошлом случае ничего не получилось и я просто закомментировал буфер координат текстуры.

```js
function drawWebglCanvas(f, v, gl, image) {
  function resizeGlAndCanvas(gl) {
    resizeCanvas(gl);
    const resizeFunc = () => {
      resizeCanvas(gl);
      render();
    };
    const lazyFunc = debounce(resizeFunc, 100);
    window.addEventListener('resize', lazyFunc);
  }
  resizeGlAndCanvas(gl);

  const vertexShader = createShader(gl, gl.VERTEX_SHADER, v);
  const fragmentShader = createShader(gl, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER, f);
  const program = createProgram(gl, vertexShader, fragmentShader);


  const positionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'a_position');
  const texcoordLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "a_texCoord");

  const positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
  setRectangle(gl, 0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

  const texCoordBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, texCoordBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([
    0.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 1.0,
    0.0, 1.0,
    1.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 1.0
  ]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

  // создаём текстуру
  const texture = gl.createTexture();
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);

  // задаём параметры, чтобы можно было отрисовать изображение любого размера
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);

  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);

  // lookup uniforms
  const resolutionLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_resolution");
  const textureSizeLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_textureSize");
  const kernelLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_kernel[0]");
  const kernelWeightLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_kernelWeight");


  const kernels = {
    normal: [
      0, 0, 0,
      0, 1, 0,
      0, 0, 0
    ],
    gaussianBlur: [
      0.045, 0.122, 0.045,
      0.122, 0.332, 0.122,
      0.045, 0.122, 0.045
    ],
    gaussianBlur2: [
      1, 2, 1,
      2, 4, 2,
      1, 2, 1
    ],
    gaussianBlur3: [
      0, 1, 0,
      1, 1, 1,
      0, 1, 0
    ],
    unsharpen: [-1, -1, -1, -1, 9, -1, -1, -1, -1],
    sharpness: [
      0, -1, 0, -1, 5, -1,
      0, -1, 0
    ],
    sharpen: [-1, -1, -1, -1, 16, -1, -1, -1, -1],
    edgeDetect: [-0.125, -0.125, -0.125, -0.125, 1, -0.125, -0.125, -0.125, -0.125],
    edgeDetect2: [-1, -1, -1, -1, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1],
    edgeDetect3: [-5, 0, 0,
      0, 0, 0,
      0, 0, 5
    ],
    edgeDetect4: [-1, -1, -1,
      0, 0, 0,
      1, 1, 1
    ],
    edgeDetect5: [-1, -1, -1,
      2, 2, 2, -1, -1, -1
    ],
    edgeDetect6: [-5, -5, -5, -5, 39, -5, -5, -5, -5],
    sobelHorizontal: [
      1, 2, 1,
      0, 0, 0, -1, -2, -1
    ],
    sobelVertical: [
      1, 0, -1,
      2, 0, -2,
      1, 0, -1
    ],
    previtHorizontal: [
      1, 1, 1,
      0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1
    ],
    previtVertical: [
      1, 0, -1,
      1, 0, -1,
      1, 0, -1
    ],
    boxBlur: [
      0.111, 0.111, 0.111,
      0.111, 0.111, 0.111,
      0.111, 0.111, 0.111
    ],
    triangleBlur: [
      0.0625, 0.125, 0.0625,
      0.125, 0.25, 0.125,
      0.0625, 0.125, 0.0625
    ],
    emboss: [-2, -1, 0, -1, 1, 1,
      0, 1, 2
    ]
  };

  const initialSelection = 'edgeDetect2';

  const ui = document.querySelector("#ui");
  const select = document.createElement("select");

  for (let name in kernels) {
    const option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = name;
    if (name === initialSelection) {
      option.selected = true;
    }
    option.appendChild(document.createTextNode(name));
    select.appendChild(option);
  }

  select.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    drawWithKernel(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);
  });

  ui.appendChild(select);
  drawWithKernel(initialSelection);

  function computeKernelWeight(kernel) {
    const weight = kernel.reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr);
    return weight <= 0 ? 1 : weight;
  }

  function drawWithKernel(name) {
    resizeCanvas(gl);
    gl.useProgram(program);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);
    const positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
  setRectangle(gl, 0, 0, gl.canvas.width,  gl.canvas.height);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(texcoordLocation);
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, texCoordBuffer);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(texcoordLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.uniform2f(resolutionLocation, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
    gl.uniform2f(textureSizeLocation, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
    gl.uniform1fv(kernelLocation, kernels[name]);
    gl.uniform1f(kernelWeightLocation, computeKernelWeight(kernels[name]));
    render();
  }

  function render() {
    const primitiveType = gl.TRIANGLES;
    const offset = 0;
    const count = 6;
    gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.drawArrays(primitiveType, offset, count);
  }
}

function setRectangle(gl, x, y, width, height) {
  const x1 = x;
  const x2 = x + width;
  const y1 = y;
  const y2 = y + height;
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([
    x1, y1,
    x2, y1,
    x1, y2,
    x1, y2,
    x2, y1,
    x2, y2,
  ]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
}

function sendGetRequest(url) {
  return fetch(url).then(response => response.text());
}

function debounce(f, t) {
  return function(args) {
    let previousCall = this.lastCall;
    this.lastCall = Date.now();
    if (previousCall && ((this.lastCall  -  previousCall) <= t)) {
      clearTimeout(this.lastCallTimer);
    }
    this.lastCallTimer = setTimeout(() => f(args), t);
  }
}

function createShader(gl, type, source) {
  const shader = gl.createShader(type);
  gl.shaderSource(shader, source);
  gl.compileShader(shader);
  const sucess = gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS);
  if (sucess) {
    return shader;
  }

  console.log(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
  gl.deleteShader(shader);
}

function createProgram(gl, v, f) {
  const program = gl.createProgram();
  gl.attachShader(program, v);
  gl.attachShader(program, f);
  gl.linkProgram(program);
  const sucess = gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.LINK_STATUS);
  if (sucess) {
    return program;
  }

  console.log(gl.getProgramInfoLog(program));
  gl.deleteProgram(program);
}

function resizeCanvas(gl) {
  const width = gl.canvas.scrollWidth
  const height = gl.canvas.scrollHeight
  gl.canvas.width = width;
  gl.canvas.height = height;
  gl.viewport(0, 0, width, height);
}

function requestCORSIfNotSameOrigin(img, url) {
  if ((new URL(url)).origin !== window.location.origin) {
    img.crossOrigin = "";
  }
}

const fragment = document.querySelector('#fragment-shader-2d').innerText;
const vertex = document.querySelector('#vertex-shader-2d').innerText;
const canvas = document.querySelector('#glcanvas');
const gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
const image = new Image();
const url = "https://picsum.photos/2000/900";
requestCORSIfNotSameOrigin(image, url);
image.src = url;
image.addEventListener('load', () => {
  drawWebglCanvas(fragment, vertex, gl, image);
});
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body,
html {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

#glcanvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}

#uiContainer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 70px;
  top: 30px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="uiContainer">
    <div id="ui"></div>
</div>

<script  id="vertex-shader-2d" type="not-js">
attribute vec2 a_texCoord;

attribute vec2 a_position;
uniform vec2 u_resolution;

varying vec2 v_texCoord;

void main() {
    // преобразуем положение в пикселях к диапазону от 0.0 до 1.0
    vec2 zeroToOne = a_position / u_resolution;

    // преобразуем из 0->1 в 0->2
    vec2 zeroToTwo = zeroToOne * 2.0;

    // преобразуем из 0->2 в -1->+1 (пространство отсечения)
    vec2 clipSpace = zeroToTwo - 1.0;

    gl_Position = vec4(clipSpace * vec2(1, -1), 0, 1);

    v_texCoord = a_texCoord;
}
</script>

<script  id="fragment-shader-2d" type="not-js">
precision mediump float;

uniform sampler2D u_image; // наша текстура
uniform vec2 u_textureSize; // размер текстуры
uniform float u_kernel[9];
uniform float u_kernelWeight;

varying vec2 v_texCoord; // texCoords, переданные из вершинного шейдера

void main(){
    // рассчитываем один пиксель в текстурных координатах
    vec2 onePixel = vec2(1.0, 1.0) / u_textureSize;

    vec4 colorSum =
        texture2D(u_image, v_texCoord + onePixel * vec2(-1, -1)) * u_kernel[0] +
        texture2D(u_image, v_texCoord + onePixel * vec2( 0, -1)) * u_kernel[1] +
        texture2D(u_image, v_texCoord + onePixel * vec2( 1, -1)) * u_kernel[2] +
        texture2D(u_image, v_texCoord + onePixel * vec2(-1,  0)) * u_kernel[3] +
        texture2D(u_image, v_texCoord + onePixel * vec2( 0,  0)) * u_kernel[4] +
        texture2D(u_image, v_texCoord + onePixel * vec2( 1,  0)) * u_kernel[5] +
        texture2D(u_image, v_texCoord + onePixel * vec2(-1,  1)) * u_kernel[6] +
        texture2D(u_image, v_texCoord + onePixel * vec2( 0,  1)) * u_kernel[7] +
        texture2D(u_image, v_texCoord + onePixel * vec2( 1,  1)) * u_kernel[8] ;

        gl_FragColor = vec4((colorSum / u_kernelWeight).rgb, 1);
}
</script>
<canvas id="glcanvas">
```

Comment: а что это такое вообще ? для чего это?  ++ поставил

Comment: @MaximLensky просто пытаюсь понять `webgl` на https://webglfundamentals.org/

Comment: ты это руками всё пишешь ?

Comment: @MaximLensky да, ну я многие куски копирую, но и пытаюсь разобраться в каждой строчке

Comment: офанареть можно - есть же там статические не изменяемые части ?

Comment: @MaximLensky не знаю что ты у меня спрашиваешь, но вот codeopen `stranger in the q`, у него там намного меньше кода, он просто разобрался и знает как сокращать https://codepen.io/strangerintheq/pen/QWboGrK

Comment: я мног раз у него был на codepen - webgl мне не интересен но всё же - 100% есть участки кода которые повторяются

Comment: я использую упрощенный способ, тут есть стадия с вершинным шейдером, которая для данного примера не нужна, но она нужна в общем случае, когда примитив не закрывает весь экран и текстурировать надо его

Comment: Тут [раз](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Games/Techniques/3D_on_the_web/GLSL_Shaders)
пишут так: "`script type="x-shader`".
А ещё там упоминается [два](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/ru/webgl-shaders-and-glsl.html)

Comment: @qwabra что вы хотели сказать? Да, я видел такое. Если в `script type` написать какой-то мусор, то html не будет воспринимать это как javascript просто

Comment: вы пишите `script type="not-js"`, мне это показалось неправильным

Comment: @МихаилКамахин, Мммм, попробовал найти такой mime type [ТУТ](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml)  - не нашел.
А [ТАМ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31254227/4794368) пишут что нужно использовать `text/plain`.
И да, я не в упрёк, а просто так ...

Comment: @qwabra для opengl

Comment: ©for GLSL files

Comment: @qwabra https://mihinov.github.io/shaders/ я тут вообще не использую `<script>`

Comment: @МихаилКамахин, не, смотрите, давайте представим, что вы написали шейдер на 300 строк .... логичнее же просто подключить его так `<script  id="fragment-shader-2d" type="text/plain" src="fragmentShader2d.glsl">` или если, например, он был создан в редакторе ....

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108048/discussion-between---and-qwabra).