# Есть ли JS библиотеки для фотообработки canvas с возможностями близкими к Photoshop?

Tags: javascript, canvas

Есть ли JS библиотеки фотообработки с возможностями близкими к Photoshop или подобных программ? Например поддержку blending mode, кривые, уровни и различные фильтры.
На гитхабе видел несколько вариантов, но зачастую все проекты заброшены и имеют маленький функционал.

Comment: Как минимум, можно на webgl сделать своё ядро свёртки и какие угодно фильтры делать https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1126094/331312

Comment: @МихаилКамахин чтоб не изобретать велосипед, думал есть уже готовые решения :)